# docker containers on different ports work differently with the same configuration

Tags: reactjs, docker

I just started learning docker, tell me pls how to fixed this trouble.
I have `docker-compose` and `Dockerfile` and two `React` projects.
First project works perfectly with this configuration:

1.Dockerfile

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

2.docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3.7'

services:

  sample:
    container_name: socket_front
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

And when in second project in `docker-compose.yml` file i just change a container_name and ports to

```
ports:
          - 4001:4000
```

In response i have `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change ports in the following way:

```
ports:
      - 4001:3000
```

4001 is the external port

3000 is the internal port.

If dockerfile is the same, there is no reason to change internal container port.